# Value in mat-form-field not being captured in the form after submission

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have implemented the functionality when one selects the postal code then the name will be rendered as shown. The issue is when I submit the form I don't see the postal code name being captured as shown by the console log below. Any thoughts of how I could fix this?

UI

[image]

Console Log

[image]

#### HTML File

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Postal Code</mat-label>
    <!-- <input matInput formControlName="businessPostalCode" required> -->
    <mat-select formControlName="businessPostalCode" [(value)]="selected" (selectionChange)="onSelectionPostalCodeChange($event.value)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let postalcode of postalcodes" [value]="postalcode.code">
        {{postalcode.code}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-error>This field is required</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Postal Code Name</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="businessPostalCodeName" [value] ="postalcode" required>
    <mat-error>This field is required</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
```

TS File

```
        this.businessRegisterformGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
          formArray: this._formBuilder.array([
            this._formBuilder.group({
              businessName: ['', Validators.required],
              businessSize: ['', Validators.required],
              numberOfEmployees: ['', Validators.required],
              kraPinNumber: ['', Validators.required],
              vatNumber: ['', Validators.required],
              businessPhoneNumber: ['', Validators.required],
              businessOtherNumber: ['', Validators.required],
              businessEmail: ['', Validators.required],
              businessFaxNumber: ['', Validators.required],
              businessPoBoxNumber: ['', Validators.required],
              businessPostalCode:  ['', Validators.required],
              businessPostalCodeName: ['', Validators.required],
              businessTown: ['', Validators.required],
              businessSubCounty: ['', Validators.required],
              businessWard:  ['', Validators.required],
            }),
        **..........**

  onSelectionPostalCodeChange(e) {
    this.postalCodeNumber = e;
    // console.log(e);

    const res = this.postalCodeDetail(e);
    const c = this.businessRegisterformGroup.patchValue({
      businessPostalCodeName: res
    });
  }

  postalCodeDetail(code) {
    this.apiPostalCodeDetail.getPostalCodeDetail(code)
      .subscribe(res => {

        this.postalcode = res.name;
        // console.log(res);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ngModel for the value of the the postal code name

```
<input matInput formControlName="businessPostalCodeName" [(ngModel)]="postalcode" required>
```

Also, you may want to JSON.parse the response from your getPostalCodeDetail call

```
this.apiPostalCodeDetail.getPostalCodeDetail(code)
      .subscribe(res => {
        // export an interface with the same structure and typings as the response
        this.exportedInterface = JSON.parse(res);
        this.postalcode = this.exportedInterface.name;
        // console.log(res);
      });
```

Exporting an interface or using a class with the same structure as the data you expect to receive is a pretty good idea. It will allow you to access the returned data more reliably. Also, about 99% of the time you receive an api response, it will be stringified for the journey, so I'm making an assumption that you need to convert your returned string into an actual object or array.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I already have the exported interface with the same structure and typings i.e **this.postalcode**. Adding the [[ngModel]] has resolved the issue.